# Hello world button?

Tags: java, android, header, development-environment

I am beginning android studio. I need to know simply how to make a button have a toast notification that says hello world. I can not find a working way to do so. Can I use the header of it for other functions?

Comment: I can not find a working way to do so--- That's good, then you can create your own code for such work. Believe me it's just a 10 minutes work.

Comment: ok thanks Ill give it a shot! :)

Comment: Follow this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: This just sounds like true laziness...

Comment: I dont understand the whole public class void thing

Comment: That actually super easy. What have you tried so far? Could you specifiy your question? What you do not understand? Maybe post some code ? The given Link of Nasser Javaid explains everthing you need.

Comment: I need to learn how to make a \n app that copys your call logs to your sd card root directory. I am doing it for my dads phone store. I kind of need it soon. Needed somewhere to start

Comment: It's a sensible question. I have a deployed App which I have been maintaining since 2012, and selling commercially. Thousands of lines of code which I can modify as an expert. However, to develop a new feature I needed to write a new blank app, and start modifying it. I haven't created an app from scratch in years. It took me about 10 minutes to add the button, and then I got stuck at popping up the toast. Google found me this question, and even then the answer didn't work (see my comment). Creating the first app in a new framework can be a forbidding task. I'm on your side, @DisplayWord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Display Word: When user clicks on the button, directly inside the XML like that:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="TextButton"
     android:onClick="buttonClickFunction"/>
```

Using the attribute android: onClick we declare the method name that has to be present on the parent activity. So i have to create this method inside our activity like that:

```
    public void buttonClickFunction(View v)
           {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
```

For details information please visit
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: getActivity() isn't in scope for me. I substituted `MainActivity.this`, where `MainActivity` is the activity name.

Answer (score 1):

create a button in .xml file

```
  <Button
 android:id="@+id/button_id"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/self_destruct"
 android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

now declare your button in activity.java file's onCreate method :

```
     Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });
```

now when you run the app and click on button it shows Toast Message "Button Clicked"

Comment: this gives me some errors like cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: add this line in your button in xml file   android:id="@+id/button_id"